# Google Sheets Convert weekly data to daily data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data that comes out of our resourcing tool (Tempo) that shows resourcing at the plan level. Plans can contain one or multiple days, but I need my data sheet to show data by day (weekends excluded) for reporting purposes.

I found a way to do this in Excel at https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-Convert-Weekly-data-to-daily-data/td-p/246673 but nothing about how to do this in google sheets.

Here is a sheet with the raw data and expected result: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OyzSiWOHK33K_I_3AAHAQcTcawK79pobOxe6QGzLQ6Y/edit?usp=sharing. I created a sheet for solutions as well.

Any help would be appreciated!